# Why is my Mac trying to force me to enroll with Expedia Group upon installation?

Tags: macos, mdm

I purchased a new Mac through Apple and I’m looking to sell my old one.  I erased the data and was going through the OS installation process.  I’m getting a popup dialog that tries to make me enroll with Expedia Group.  I purchased this laptop directly from Apple in 2015 and have been the sole owner.  It’s a personal laptop.  How can I bypass this?

Comment: Are you using original OSX install disks or some hacked version..? Could you edit your question to include a screenshot or photo of this pop-up..? It sounds highly irregular to me.

Comment: This sounds like MDM.   Is this the first time you’re doing an OS install on this particular Mac?

Answer (score 20):

Contact Apple support with your purchase details and ask them to fix the enrollment of the serial number on the affected Mac. It sounds like there was a clerical mixup on the record keeping as part of automated device enrollment.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204142

They will be able to review your process for erasing the old Mac and also confirm exactly what’s happening without you needing to post any more details here. Feel free to comment if you answer some of the questions asking for clarification on your question - or if you post more details in an edit to your question.